# Decision tree classification gives two branches with the same output

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am training my decision tree using the mtcars dataset, but to my surprise I have noticed that some of the terminal leaves are the same (e.g. the mpg splits on the right) when I am using "deviance" as a split parameter, but it seems fixed when I am using "gini" as a split parameter. Is there any theoretical explanation for that? Is it because the terminal leaves are too few? When I tried to find the optimal tree size (by train/validation) it was 3.

[image]

I created the tree using the R tree package and plotted this in R using the following code:

```
RNGversion("3.5.2")
options(scipen=999)
library(e1071)
library(tree)
library(MASS)
mt = mtcars
#Function to calculate misclassification rate
missclass=function(actualData,predictedData){
  n=length(actualData)
  return(1-sum(diag(table(actualData,predictedData)))/n)
}
mt$am = as.factor(mt$am)
n = dim(mt)[1]
set.seed(12345)
id = sample(1:n,floor(n*0.5))
train = mt[id,]
id1 = setdiff(1:n,id)
set.seed(12345)
id2 = sample(id1,floor(n*0.5))
test = mt[id2,]

tree_1 = tree(am~.,data = train)
summary(tree_1)
terminalNodes = 3
trainScore = rep(0,terminalNodes)
validationScore = rep(0,terminalNodes)
missclassification_Rate = c()
for(i in 2:terminalNodes){
  tree_1_Prune = prune.tree(tree_1,best=i)
  print(i)
  pred = predict(tree_1_Prune,newdata = test,type="tree")
  trainScore[i] = deviance(tree_1_Prune)
  validationScore[i] = deviance(pred)
}
plot(2:terminalNodes,trainScore[2:terminalNodes],type="l",col="red",pch =
       "o",ylim=c(0,20),ylab = "Train/Test Score",xlab="No. of Leaves")
points(2:terminalNodes,trainScore[2:terminalNodes],col="red")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(2:terminalNodes,validationScore[2:terminalNodes],type="l",
     ylim=c(0,20),col="blue",pch = "o",ylab = "Train/Test Score",yaxt="n",xlab="No.of Leaves")
points(2:terminalNodes,validationScore[2:terminalNodes],col="blue")
legend(x="center",legend = c("Test","Train"),lwd=1,col=c("Blue","Red"),lty=1)
final_Pruned_Tree = prune.tree(tree_1,best = 3)
summary(final_Pruned_Tree)
plot(final_Pruned_Tree)
text(final_Pruned_Tree,pretty = 0)
pred_test_using_pruned_tree = stats::predict(final_Pruned_Tree,test,type="class")
```

Comment: @MrFlick I have noticed that when using "gini" as a split parameter, I am getting the correct split. Still getting the aforementioned wrong split when I use "deviance" as a split parameter.


tree_1 = tree(am~.,data = train,split = c("gini"))

vs

tree_1 = tree(am~.,data = train,split = c("deviance"))

Is deviance the default split when it is not specified?

Comment: That's useful information I would edit into the question itself rather than leaving it in the comments.